# Sequelize Error: .belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hey im trying to design my database architecture so a user can be part of many teams, and a team can have many users. I've created a junction table TeamMembers to achieve this, but im getting an error.

**Error: TeamMember.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model**

This is happening when I create a new database from scratch. So there will be no users or teams, or any data in any table.

//User Model

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../database')

class User extends Model {}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    recoveryEmail: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    profilePicture: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    jobTitle: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    bio: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    hash: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    admin: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    notifications: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    currentTeamId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
    tableName: 'users',
    defaultScope: {
      attributes: {
        exclude: ['hash'] /* By default, DO NOT include password */
      }
    },
    scopes: {
      /* Add a scope for getting with password, use this only intentionally */
      withPassword: {
        attributes: {},
      },
    },
  }
)

module.exports = User
```

//Team Model

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../database')

const { User } = require('./index')

class Team extends Model {}

Team.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    profilePicture: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    ownerId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: User,
        key: 'id',
      }
    }
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Team',
    tableName: 'teams',
  }
)

module.exports = Team
```

//Team Member model

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../database')

const { User, Team } = require('./index')

class TeamMember extends Model {}

TeamMember.init({
  userId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: User,
      key: 'id',
    },
    allowNull: false
  },
  teamId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Team,
      key: 'id',
    },
    allowNull: false
  },
  role: {
    type: DataTypes.ENUM('Super Admin', 'Admin', 'Member'),
    allowNull: false,
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'TeamMember',
  tableName: 'team_members'
})

module.exports = TeamMember
```

//models/index

```
const User = require('./userModel')
const Team = require('./teamModel')
const TeamMember = require('./teamMemberModel')
require('./associations')

module.exports = {
  User,
  Team,
  TeamMember
}
```

//models/associations

```
const { User, Team, TeamMember } = require('./index')

User.hasMany(TeamMember, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
User.hasMany(Team, { foreignKey: 'ownerId' })

Team.hasMany(TeamMember, { foreignKey: 'teamId' })

TeamMember.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
TeamMember.belongsTo(Team, { foreignKey: 'teamId' })
```

Assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: We'd need to see your associations file to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency between those three models, they each load the other two. Something had to give. It has to choose to complete loading one file before the others have finished.

If you check `User` and `Team` before the call to `TeamMember.belongsTo` it's likely one of them is null.

You can break this dependency by putting the models in one file, and the circular associations in its own file which loads the models.

Alternatively, you can put all three models and their associations in one file which exports all three classes.

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../database')

class User extends Model {}

User.init(
  ...
)

module.exports = User


class Team extends Model {}

Team.init(
  ...
)

module.exports = Team

class TeamMember extends Model {}

TeamMember.init({
  ...
})


module.exports = TeamMember

User.hasMany(TeamMember, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
User.hasMany(Team, { foreignKey: 'ownerId' })

Team.hasMany(TeamMember, { foreignKey: 'teamId' })

TeamMember.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
TeamMember.belongsTo(Team, { foreignKey: 'teamId' })
```

---

**UPDATE**

> With all the associations from the models in there properly, i get the same error as when they are apart. Thanks

(Assuming `index` is the associations file) you still have a circular dependency. The models all reference `index` which references all three models. The models cannot depend on the associations file, it has to be loaded separately.

The models should refer to only the other model files: `const { User } = require('./userModel')` and so on.

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../database')

class User extends Model {}

User.init(
  ...
)

module.exports = User
```

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../database')

const { User } = require('./userModel')

class Team extends Model {}

Team.init(
  ...
)

module.exports = Team
```

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../database')

const { User } = require('./userModel')
const { Team } = require('./teamModel')

class TeamMember extends Model {}

TeamMember.init({
  ...
})

module.exports = TeamMember
```

Then your associations file loads the models. The associations file doesn't export anything, it's just there to add the associations to the models.

```
const { User } = require('./userModel')
const { Team } = require('./teamModel')
const { TeamMember } = require('./teamMemberModel')

User.hasMany(TeamMember, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
User.hasMany(Team, { foreignKey: 'ownerId' })

Team.hasMany(TeamMember, { foreignKey: 'teamId' })

TeamMember.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
TeamMember.belongsTo(Team, { foreignKey: 'teamId' })
```

Finally, for convenience, your models index can load the models and associations, to ensure everything is loaded, and export the models. This is what the user of your models will require.

```
const { User } = require('./userModel')
const { Team } = require('./teamModel')
const { TeamMember } = require('./teamMemberModel')
require('./teamAssociations')

module.exports = {
  User,
  Team,
  TeamMember
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply and willingness to help me fix this.

Ive updated the question with an associations file, if you could kindly take another look.

Im actually getting the same error still now and not the "is not a function error", as when i created the associations file i forgot a couple of associations in there. With all the associations from the models in there properly, i get the same error as when they are apart.

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to say that this is happening when I create a new database from scratch. So there will be no users or teams, or any data in any table.

Comment: @SamKing See the update to my answer.

Comment: Hey @Schwern. I tried that but to no avail. Ive updated my question to show what i've changed per your comment. Maybe I missed something? The error i get now is: Error: User.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Comment: @SamKing The models depend on index, index depends on the models; still circular. The models should depend directly on each other. The associations file depends on the models. You can have a third file which depends on the models and the associations and then re-exports the models to ensure everything is loaded, but that's for other code to use.

Comment: @SamKing See the update. I might not be 100% correct, I'm on a phone, but I hope that explains it.

Comment: Hi @Schwern. My brain has a circular dependency after all that. It seems to be working now and I greatly appreciate your assistance - especially on a phone. I feel privileged to have been helped by a top 0.01% stackoverflow-er. Have a good day my friend.